# React UseEffect is being calling twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in FC component:

**I just want to call the Api and Log the info when the component is mounted**

The console.log is being called twice for empty array and twice for setting the same values.

```
import * as React from"react";
import Header from"../components/Header";
import Search from"../components/Search";
import Categories from"../components/Categories";
import Carousel from"../components/Carousel";
import CarouselItem from"../components/CarouselItem";
import Footer from"../components/Footer";
import "../assets/styles/App.scss";

const App = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/initalState")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setVideos(data));
  }, []);

  console.log(videos);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header></Header>
      <Search></Search>

      <Categories title="Mi Lista">
        <Carousel>
          <CarouselItem />
          <CarouselItem />
          <CarouselItem />
          <CarouselItem />
          <CarouselItem />
        </Carousel>
      </Categories>

      <Categories title="Tendencias">
        <Carousel>
          <CarouselItem />
          <CarouselItem />
        </Carousel>
      </Categories>

      <Categories title="Originales de Platzi Video">
        <Carousel>
          <CarouselItem />
        </Carousel>
      </Categories>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

However, i got the following output:

[image]

Calling within useEffect:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/initalState")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setVideos(data);
        console.log(videos);
      });
  }, []);
```

returns an empty array.

Comment: you are printing it outside. Try printing it within the useEffect callback.

Comment: Also verify there is only one `<App/>` component being mounted. Probably is but clearing the obvious first helps

Comment: Yes, just one App is being mounted.

Comment: @AmitJoki i just updated this post for printing inside useEffect callback, gives me an empty array.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I just realized I was rendering App in strict Mode, ***which invokes some events twice:***

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method Function
> component bodies State updater functions (the first argument to
> setState) Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

I had this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

Now

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

It's solved.

Comment: you helpme very much

Comment: Removing `StrictMode` should be the last choice. For a more detailed answer, you may visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/useeffect-is-running-twice-on-mount-in-react.

Answer (score 2):

you can use UseCallback to avoid an additional run below is the sample code.

Note: If you directly call setTimeout/server calls inside use effect without wrapping in `useCallback` , it will be called twice

```
const App = () => {
  const [myData, setMyData] = React.useState([]);


  const getData = useCallback ( () => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Inside setTimeOut");
      setMyData("HEllo");
    }, 2000);

  }, [] )

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
     console.log("Inside UseEffect",myData);
   },[getData]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
     Inside my App {myData}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Output:**

```
Inside UseEffect  [printed just once]
```

Comment: I understand. Should i use console.logs outside the useEffect hooks? Same level as useEffect, return and getData?

Comment: Nope. Then it will have more cycles , as getdata will have new data  which will render again and prints log again. By wrapping i `useEffect` and adding dependency it will not run unless dependency changes

Comment: I have removed all the `myData` dependencies and kept the other `console` prints. It prints `Inside UseEffect` twice