# useEffect rendering form from script twice on load?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, addeventlistener, use-effect

I am using a hubspot form in my next.js site - I want to render the form on page load as you can see in the code.

The undesired effect is that the form renders twice, I want to build in a system so it only renders on page load and thats it. How do I achieve this?

I tried to follow this to solve it but did not work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzH6YxW0zW4.

Code below

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let isCancelled = false;

        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "//js-eu1.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js";
        document.body.appendChild(script)
        
        if (!isCancelled) {
            script.addEventListener('load', () => {
                if (window.hbspt){
                    hubspotForm();
                }
            })
        }

        return () => {
            isCancelled = true
        };
    }, [])
```

Comment: Are you using `<StrictMode>` and react 18?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React 18, useEffect is getting called two times on mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount)

Answer (score 2):

Removing strict mode is something that you should not prefer. I believe if you do this:

```
  useEffect(() => {


    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//js-eu1.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    const listener=() => {
            if (window.hbspt){
                hubspotForm();
            }
        }
        script.addEventListener('load', listener)


    return () => {
       script.removeEventListener('load',listener)
    };
}, [])
```

it should work fine. I prepared a detailed explanation of the topic (why useEffect is running twice and how to handle it.) [here](https://dev.to/sjtgshivam/useeffect-in-react18-1449) if you might want to have a look. Removing Strict mode is an easy out way but you should not choose it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove strict mode from your index.js, that should do the trick.

Comment: Awh is it really that simple - so in production it wont render twice?

Comment: Try it out Michael and see if it works.

Comment: Yes I changed the config in next.config.js to turn of strictmode and it renders twice still maybe its a hubspot issue

Comment: it's a react18 issue sometimes the concurrent state update can cause it to render more than once even in production built, You can refer to this video to fix this issue : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvuXkRnZi8g

Answer (score 0):

check the version of `react` and `react-dom` in the `package.json` file
if you're using the lastest version of react v18. Because of the react strict mode and concurrrent rendering feature it executes the `useEffect()` hook to run twice even the if you set an empty dependency array.

you can disable react strictmode from `next.config.js` file

it should help to fix your problem

Comment: Yes I changed the config in next.config.js to turn of strictmode and it renders twice still maybe its a hubspot issue

Comment: did you restarted your dev server after changing the `next.config.js` file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // check whether the script is present already
  if (document.getElementById('your-script-id')) return;
  
  let isCancelled = false;

  const script = document.createElement('script');
  // add an id here
  script.id = "your-script-id";

  // the rest of your code
}
```

Also, check that you're not re-mounting your component, the fact that your script is triggered twice suggests that somewhere outside your component is re-mounted on load, which might cause performance issues.