# React Fetch API Being Called 2 Times on page load

Tags: javascript, npm, axios

React Fetch API Being Called 2 Times on page load, I don't know what is missing in this code or what I am doing wrong. I have faced this problem from the morning,
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios';
    import {  Grid, Paper, TextField } from '@mui/material'
    import PersonOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PersonOutline';
    
    function FormApi() {
    
      //Mui fileds and paper style
      const paperStyle = { padding: '50px ', width: 550, margin: '50px auto' }
    
      //Fetch data from api
      const [userx, setUserx] = useState([{data:null,support:null}]);
      const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2';
    
        useEffect(()=>{
    
          //debugger
    
          const fetchData = async () =>{
    
            await axios.get(`${url}`)
            .then((response) =>{
              setUserx(response.data)
    
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
            })
          }
    
          fetchData();
          }
    
        ,[]);
    
      return (
    
        <Grid container spacing={2} style={paperStyle}>
    
          <Grid align='center' >
            <Paper elevation={20} >
    
              <Grid align='center'>
    
                <h2 style={{padding:'10px' ,background: "#000080", color: 'white' }}> 
       <PersonOutlineIcon large style={{fontSize:'80%'}} />User Details</h2>
    
              </Grid>
              
              <form>
             
              <img style={{width:"20%"}} src={userx.data  ? userx.data.avatar : ''}/>
                <h1 style={{color:'#000080'}}>{userx.data  ? userx.data.first_name : ''} 
       {userx.data  ? userx.data.last_name : ''}</h1>
    
              <Grid container >
                <Grid item xs={6} >
                  <h2 style={{color:'white', background: "purple"}}>Contact Info</h2>
                  <TextField   value={userx.data  ? userx.data.id : ''}   variant="standard" 
         />
                  <TextField  value={userx.data  ? userx.data.email  : ''}   
       variant="standard" />
                </Grid>
    
                <Grid item align='left' xs={6} style={{marginBottom:'40px'}}>
                  <h2 style={{color:'white', background: "purple"}}>Social Link</h2>
                  <TextField  value={userx.support ? userx.support.url : ''}   
       variant="standard" />
                  <TextField  value={userx.support ? userx.support.text : ''}     
      variant="standard" />
                </Grid>
                
              </Grid>
              </form>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>       
      )
    }enter code here
    
    export default FormApi
```

Comment: Do you have `StrictMode` enabled?

Comment: This is normal behaviour in React 18 
https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state. It will only be done on development environments and when StrictMode is enabled.

Answer (score 15):

It's because React renders components 2 times in the development environment. To avoid this, you can comment out the `<React.StrictMode>` tag in `index.js` file.

Rendering twice will only appear in the **development environment** and StrictMode has many benefits for development:

- Identifying components with unsafe lifecycles
- Warning about legacy string ref API usage
- Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage
- Detecting unexpected side effects
- Detecting legacy context API
- Ensuring reusable state

So it's better to keep the `<React.StrictMode>` tag if it doesn't affect your normal development work.

See also: [React StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Answer (score 7):

This is normal behaviour in [React 18](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state). It will only be done on development environments and when StrictMode is enabled and will not be a problem in your production Build.

A bit annoying, but nothing really to worry about. There is a workaround which you can learn more about in a in-depth answer here:
[React 18, useEffect is getting called two times on mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount)

Answer (score 4):

You can handle it with useRef hook, but it's totally fine. it happens only in dev mode.

```
const renderAfterCalled = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!renderAfterCalled.current) {
      // your API call func
    }

    renderAfterCalled.current = true;
}, []);
```

removing `<React.StrictMode>` can also solve the issue but avoid removing `<React.StrictMode>`.
it's a helpful tool during development that checks for potential issues and warns about unsafe practices.

Answer (score 0):

as much as I know, this issue is caused by the HTTTP client sending 2 request, one to the route path "/" and the other to "/favicon.ico"

make this change :

`useEffect(()=>{`
`checkLocation();`
`//your code`
 `,[]);`

Comment: What? `fetch` doesn't ask for a favicon unless you specifically make that request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

after some revision
try this

function FormApi() {

```
  //Mui fileds and paper style
  const paperStyle = { padding: '50px ', width: 550, margin: '50px auto' }

  //Fetch data from api
  const [userx, setUserx] = useState([{data:null,support:null}]);
  const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2';
//debugger

      const fetchData = async () =>{

        await axios.get(`${url}`)
        .then((response) =>{
          setUserx(response.data)

        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
      }

    useEffect(()=>{

      
      fetchData();
      }

    ,[]);
```