# Axios.get Firing Twice

Tags: reactjs, axios

So I have a block of code the effectively is taking the url and translating that to a request to an Open API.

The issue is that for whatever reason my axios.get seems to be executed twice. Relatively new developer in React and I I am guessing I am overlooking something fundamental.

Any advice would be greatly received. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import configData from './config/config.json'


const Article  = () => { 

    console.log('0')
    const requestarticle = useParams();
    console.log('1')
    const [url] = useState(configData.BACKEND_URL + '/articles/' + requestarticle.page)
    console.log('2')
    const [article, setArticle] = useState(null)
    console.log('3')

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('4')
        axios.get(url)
            .then(Response => 
                {setArticle(Response.data)}
                )
    }, [url])


    if (article){
        return ( 
            <>
            <div id="page-content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: article.content}} class="container-sm text-start border border-dark rounded border-3"></div>
            </>
            );
        }

        return(

            <h1> NOTHING TO RETURN</h1>

        )
  
}
 
export default Article ;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React 18, useEffect is getting called two times on mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to <[StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)> most likely in your root tree.

**What is strict mode?**

> StrictMode is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an application.

**How does it make `useEffect()` run twice?**

> It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants, or in other words... renders twice.

`Note:` Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not impact the production build.