# react repeat request multiple time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building a React component but when rendering the component, the request done two times even if the first request success

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import Post from './Post';

export const SinglePost = () => {

   const { id } = useParams();
   const getData =  async() => {
       await axios.get(`post/${id}`)
       .then((response)=>{
          return response.data
       })
       .catch((err)=>{
          return err
       })
   }
  return <Post post = {getData()} />
}
```

Is there a common way to fix it? Thanks.

Here my `index.tsx`

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);

root.render(
 <Provider store ={store}>
    <App />
 </Provider>
);
```

The error happens I think when passing the result to `Post` component. Even in that component, the request to that URL is never made.

**Edit**

I am rendering the component inside `app.tsx` by this code

```
<Route path="post/:id" element={<SinglePost/>}/>
```

**Edit2**

Post object contains:

```
Object { id: 132, content: "", updated: "2022-10-08T09:56:37.070618Z", image: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/admin%40socialbook.org/posts/b2e5d26fff1965a4.jpeg", created: "2022-10-08T09:56:37.070618Z", author: {…} }
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72489140/react-18-strict-mode-causing-component-to-render-twice

Comment: @KostasMinaidis strict mode is already disabled

Comment: Can you supply the code where the SinglePost Component is used?

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to execute getData() inside the Post prop but inside a useEffect.

Comment: I tried to execute it inside useEffect but it wont execute at all due the return post error

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I add the component load route

Comment: can you provide what's inside post component

Comment: @omar I will add that as an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why it throws an error, is because the component did not mount to call `useEffect`, so I think giving initial value to the state that holds post will work, for example:

```js
var initialValue = {
    info:"",
    author:"",
    content:""
}
```

outside the component
then define `const [singlePost, setSinglePost] = useState(initialValue)`

Inside your component finally when you get a response set that response to `setSinglePost`

Comment: but the component load empty before load content and image

Comment: use spinner to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with `React.StrictMode`. If you remove this, it should only render once.

I believe that this only happens in development. In production this wouldn't happen, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I added the index.tsx as an Edit, strict mode is removed before that error occure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [React Strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), and it only happens in development. It's enabled by default for your whole React app.
If you wish to remove it, go to your `index.js` and remove the tags `<React.StrictMode>` wrapping your app.

Comment: I added the index.tsx as an Edit, strict mode is removed before that error occure

Comment: Are you using a useEffect hook in your code? I see you imported it.
If so, then it is due to the useEffect that gets triggered after rendering.
I suggest you put your request in a useEffect with empty dependacy array, and without any other useEffects in the page.

Comment: I tried to execute it inside useEffect but it wont execute at all due the return post error, and I also tried without useEffect