# What to do with React StrictMode when it causes problem with instance creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that React StrictMode renders my component twice.  But I have a use case where this causes problems and I am not sure how to fix (and if I have to fix).

What the code below does :

1. On mount, it instantiates a webrct connection and a websocket connection.
2. On unmount, it closes the webrtc connection and closes the websocket connection

Because I am using async calls to instantiate objects , my objects are not fully constructed when the ummount is triggered.  The second mount is then triggered and this create a second websocket alive connection, which is causing me problems

```
let rtc = null;

const init = async () => {
  if (!rtc) {
    rtc = new WebRTCConnection();
    await rtc.init("ws://localhost:8080");
    document.getElementById("studentPeer").srcObject = rtc.localStream;
    document.getElementById("vcsPositionPeer").srcObject = rtc.remoteStream;
  }
};

const Recognition = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Anything in here is fired on component mount.
    init();
    return () => {
      // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.
      if (rtc) rtc.release();
      rtc=null;
    };
  }, []);

  return (...
```

As a solution, I thought to transform my WebRTCConnection object to be full synced.  In this case, the mount will wait for the full creation of the instance before calling the unmount.  But I feel this is contrary to the philosophy of async...

**So, should I fix this by removing async, or remove StrictMode (which I think is recommended to keep)?**

Comment: how did you decide to work around this eventually ?

Comment: @DragosPodaru Unfortunately, I disabled StrictMode :(

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72489175/9897918) are the appropriate answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72489175/9897918

Comment: In Strict.Mode, the problem was solved in the following way
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78112805/9897918

Comment: In Strict.Mode, the problem was solved in the following way
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78112805/9897918

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72585970/9897918

> React 18 now has Strict.Mode which can mount, unmount, and remount components which causes the abortController to issue an error on the first unmount. Remember, this only happens in development mode when Strict.Mode is applied in your index.js. We can check for that behaviour while in development-mode.
> https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Comment: How does this answer the question of choosing between the two options that were asked to be considered?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).