# What exactly does it mean that a component unmounts in React? Does it disappear after it's unmounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

let say I have a functional `Home` component:

```
const Home = () => {
  console.log('outside useEffect')
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('inside useEffect')
    
    // cleanup function
    return () => { console.log('unmounted') }
  }, [])

  return <div>Hello Word</div>
}
```

The output in the console shows:

```
outside useEffect
inside useEffect
unmounted
inside useEffect
```

My questions are:

1. When does the component `unmount`, does it happen automatically after it has rendered once or when?
2. What exactly does happen when the component `unmounts`? Does the component get deleted/removed? If yes then how am I still able to see the `Hello World`  even if it `unmounts`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally a component gets *unmounted* when for example it's rendered conditionally and the conditional become `false`. `DummyComponent` below gets *unmounted* every time `state` become  `false`. And when a component is *unmounted*, it's removed from the `DOM`, and therefore you won't see it in the page.

```js
const DummyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted");
    return () => {
      console.log("unmounted");
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>Hello Word</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>Toggle Dummy Component</button>
      {state ? <DummyComponent /> : <></>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

What you are seeing in your case is introduced by React version `18` where each component gets `mounted` and immediately *unmounted* and *mounted* again, when you are in development with `StrictMode`: it's explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount). And it's so quick that you are not noticing the change visually.

Answer (score 2):

In React 18 Strict Mode, each component is unmounted & remounted again.
https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html

Perhaps that's why "inside useEffect" is printed after "unmount".