# useEffect function triggers multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from a local json-server and display it in a list using react.

From my understanding the useEffect should trigger a console log twice in this instance. One empty return for the countries and one populated one.

If someone is able to let me know why this console.log get's triggered so often I'd be really thankful.

**The react code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function CountryList() {

  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/countries')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setCountries(data))
      
    }, [])
    
    console.log(countries)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>CountryList</h2>

      <ul>
        {countries.map(country => (
          <li key={country.name}>{country.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**The console however returns the following:**

[image]

**The json-server get's this list of countries:**

```
{
  "countries": [
    { 
      "name": "Austria", 
      "code": "AT", 
      "language": "german",
      "cities": {
        "Vienna": {
          "population": "8.3 million",
          "latitude": "48.208174",
          "longitude": "16.373819"
        },
        "Graz": {
          "population": "1.5 million",
          "latitude": "47.070713",
          "longitude": "15.439186"
        }
      },
      "currency": {
        "code": "EUR",
        "name": "Euro",
        "symbol": "€"
      }
    },

    {
      "name": "Greece", 
      "code": "GR", 
      "language": "greek",
      "cities": {
        "Athens": {
          "population": "2.7 million",
          "latitude": "37.983810",
          "longitude": "23.727539"
        },
        "Thessaloniki": {
          "population": "1.5 million",
          "latitude": "40.633125",
          "longitude": "22.944406"
        },
        "Patras": {
          "population": "1.5 million",
          "latitude": "38.244818",
          "longitude": "21.738050"
        }
      },
      "currency": {
        "code": "EUR",
        "name": "Euro",
        "symbol": "€"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What's your React version?

Comment: I'm running ver. 18.2.0

Comment: Are you using StrictMode in index.js file, if yes then remove it

Comment: @MridulGupta read question correctly OP is asking why both console.log have same result, also disabling strictmode is stupid

Comment: This thread might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount @lechnerio.

Comment: I think request was cached, may be thats why happened quickly ?. try checking "disable cache" in network tab of dev tools.

Comment: @bogdanoff you need to read it carefully, as far as I know, he is saying console.log should be printed only 2 times, once for the empty array and once when the data is fetched and the state is populated and his follow-up is why so many console.log's are getting triggered

Comment: @MridulGupta how does disabling strictmode helps, it might stop showing 2 times but he'll lose may advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid having console.log outside of any function.
As react native life-cycle mount and re-mount happen when dom changes.
Best way to check state value is as follows.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this logs when countries array changes.
    console.log(countries)      
}, [countries])
```