# React fetch sending request multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm trying fetching data in react. I call the fetch function only once but it's sending request multiple times but I don't know why. I looked other questions and tried their answers but none of them worked.

When I delete `useEffect` and leave the function alone, it sends a request once, but I think this is not the right way.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchFunction();
}, [])

const fetchFunction =() => {
  console.log("ldşsaşdlisaldi")
  axios.get(
    "someAPI",
    {
      headers: {
        "Authorization" : localStorage.getItem("token")
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    }
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setTableData(result);
      },
      (error) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setError(error);
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you checked by the way if your index.js is running strict mode. It's for development purposes only, if it is try removing strict mode and retry is see if the request are still running twice.

Comment: I deleted it but it still running twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React 18, useEffect is getting called two times on mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount)

Comment: I understood properly now. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Don't*** attempt to do any sort of "initial mount" check or "state" as this is considered anti-pattern. Don't try to "outsmart" React. The double-mounting is a way for the `React.StrictMode` component to help you see unexpected side-effects and other issues. You should implement a cleanup function to cancel any in-flight requests when the component unmounts. Use an [`abortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) with the `axios` GET request.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController(); // <-- create controller

  fetchFunction({ controller }); // <-- pass controller

  return () => controller.abort(); // <-- return cleanup function
}, []);

const fetchFunction = ({ controller }) => {
  axios.get("someAPI", {
    headers: {
      "Authorization" : localStorage.getItem("token")
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    signal: controller.signal // <-- pass signal to request
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      setTableData(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {;
      setError(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
    });
}
```

For more details and explanation see [Fetching Data](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data).