# For some reason I am getting 4 responses when I should be getting one using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, axios

enter image description here

[image]tps://i.stack.imgur.com/ELZJw.png
[image]
[image]
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: The composition here is really interesting, but maybe post your code and errors as text

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner so my code is highly unorganized and all over the place spanning many files. That is why I decided to post images of the parts that I think are related to the problem

Comment: If you know which parts are problematic you should be able to construct a [mcve] here, which would be very helpful towards getting your question answered. Working with image snippets of others' code is very error-prone and often a waste of time for answerers.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `router.get` only one time in one place in an `useEffect`. And if you are using React 18 this thread might help: [React 18, useEffect is getting called two times on mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].