# why use effect running tow time in react even i have define empty square breakets in second perameter of useEffect method?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

my useEffect Hook syntax:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let compeleteArray = allQuestion[questionIndex].incorrect_answers.push(
    allQuestion[questionIndex].correct_answer
  );
  setAllOptions(allQuestion[questionIndex].incorrect_answers);
  console.log(allQuestion[questionIndex].incorrect_answers);
  console.log("running");
  console.log(
    "addCorrect:",
    compeleteArray,
    "allQuestion.correct_answer:",
    allQuestion[questionIndex].correct_answer
  );
}, []);
```

Even I have define Empty Array for running once time !!

Comment: if any other details of code needed  for answering then please let me know,

Comment: It might be because of Strict Mode .... can you see if `index.js` has this mode wrapped to `App` / `Main` component

Comment: I have rolled back your recent edit because 1) it invalidated the existing answer (once your question has received an answer, you're not allowed to fundamentally alter it), and 2) the new question you wrote is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It may be on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), but do check their rules and expectations before posting.

Answer (score 1):

useEffect Run Twice in React v18

It happens only in development mode. If you want to disable it, you can remove strict mode in src/index.js. But that is not recommended.

In Production mode, the useEffect hook will run only once. To disable in development stage, you can do as follow

```
root.render(
//  <StrictMode> // comment this line
    <App />
//  </StrictMode> // and this this line
);
```

You can know more from [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-v18-0-useeffect-bug-why-do-effects-run-twice-39babecede93)

Comment: For a more detailed answer you can visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/72238236/15288641.