# React Firebase getDocs & useEffect makes two calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to get data from firebase in react, using useEffect to avoid creating loops.

My code works so far, but I get the results twice. When I tried to find out what the problem was, I found that the data was also retrieved twice. Because the whole code section is executed twice.

--> i get the "Did request!" from `console.log("Did request!")` 2x times

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase-config";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

function MusicList() {
  const [musicList, setMusicList] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "music"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setMusicList((oldArray) => [...oldArray, doc.data()]);
      });
      console.log("Did request!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="MusicList">
      {musicList.map((music) => {
        return <div key={music.id}>{music.songName}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MusicList;
```

Being relatively new to React and the concept of "useEffect" I don't know exactly why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you have React strict mode enabled? It does this very annoying thing where it renders components twice. Remove it and it should only render once. Let me know if it works:

```
<StrictMode> <<--- remove this
  <App />
</StrictMode> <<--- remove this
```

UPDATE: I should mention this is a quick fix. The double rendering is done to ensure you've put in features such as query caching etc where bugs can be detected by double rendering.

Further information: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502#issuecomment-1118754581

Comment: Removing `SrictMode` is a bad idea. To handle it well see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react