# Why the function in useEffect resulting two calls in the console?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

**Whenever the component renders there are two success messages are shown in the console. Shouldn't it call only once?**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/workouts");
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(json);
        setWorkouts(json);
      }
    };

    fetchWorkouts();
  }, []);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, I'm not using <strictMode>

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Yeah, it's in the index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
```

Or

```
 <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
```

in your `index.js` in the root folder, just removing it will fix the issue.

You can read more about the `StrictMode` in react.js [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: Removing `StrictMode` is a bad idea. This behavior is not an issue; it's wanted. For a detailed answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react