# why does my createAsyncThunk function fetch data multiple times instead of once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am trying to make a simple blog webpage with react and redux(going along a tutorial). I created a redux store, made a posts slice that is used to manage everything that has to do with the posts and i am having some issues with fetching the data using redux thunk. When i run the blog page i see two of every post. Not sure if the issue is from the component i used to dispatch the fetchPosts() function and display the posts or some error i made in the slice itself. Below is my code and a jsFiddle with my project. I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me check where i went wrong.

PostsList.js

```
const PostsList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const posts = useSelector(selectAllPosts);
  const postStatus = useSelector(getPostsStatus);
  const error = useSelector(getPostsError);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (postStatus === "idle") {
      dispatch(fetchPosts());
    }
  }, [postStatus, dispatch]);

  let content;
  if (postStatus === "loading") {
    content = <p>"Loading..."</p>;
  } else if (postStatus === "succeeded") {
    const orderedPosts = posts
      .slice()
      .sort((a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date));
    content = orderedPosts.map((post) => (
      <PostsExcerpt key={post.id} post={post} />
    ));
  } else if (postStatus === "failed") {
    content = <p>{error}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Posts</h2>
      {content}
    </section>
  );
};
export default PostsList;
```

PostsSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, nanoid, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { sub } from "date-fns";
import axios from "axios";

const POSTS_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  status: "idle",
  error: null,
};

//Fetch Posts Function
export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/fetchPosts", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(POSTS_URL);
  return response.data;
});

export const addNewPost = createAsyncThunk(
  "posts/addNewPost",
  async (initialPost) => {
    const response = await axios.post(POSTS_URL, initialPost);
    return response.data;
  }
);

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    postAdded: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        state.posts.push(action.payload);
      },
      prepare(title, content, userId) {
        return {
          payload: {
            id: nanoid(),
            title,
            content,
            date: new Date().toISOString(),
            userId,
            reactions: {
              thumbsUp: 0,
              wow: 0,
              heart: 0,
              rocket: 0,
              coffee: 0,
            },
          },
        };
      },
    },
    reactionAdded(state, action) {
      const { postId, reaction } = action.payload;
      const existingPost = state.posts.find((post) => post.id === postId);
      if (existingPost) {
        existingPost.reactions[reaction]++;
      }
    },
  },

  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchPosts.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "succeeded";
        // Adding date and reactions
        let min = 1;
        const loadedPosts = action.payload.map((post) => {
          post.date = sub(new Date(), { minutes: min++ }).toISOString();
          post.reactions = {
            thumbsUp: 0,
            wow: 0,
            heart: 0,
            rocket: 0,
            coffee: 0,
          };
          return post;
        });

        // Add any fetched posts to the array
        state.posts = state.posts.concat(loadedPosts);
      })
      .addCase(fetchPosts.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })
      .addCase(addNewPost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        // Fix for API post IDs:
        // Creating sortedPosts & assigning the id
        // would be not be needed if the fake API
        // returned accurate new post IDs
        const sortedPosts = state.posts.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.id > b.id) return 1;
          if (a.id < b.id) return -1;
          return 0;
        });
        action.payload.id = sortedPosts[sortedPosts.length - 1].id + 1;
        // End fix for fake API post IDs

        action.payload.userId = Number(action.payload.userId);
        action.payload.date = new Date().toISOString();
        action.payload.reactions = {
          thumbsUp: 0,
          hooray: 0,
          heart: 0,
          rocket: 0,
          eyes: 0,
        };
        console.log(action.payload);
        state.posts.push(action.payload);
      });
  },
});

export const selectAllPosts = (state) => state.posts.posts;
export const getPostsStatus = (state) => state.posts.status;
export const getPostsError = (state) => state.posts.error;

export const { postAdded, reactionAdded } = postsSlice.actions;

export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

This is the outcome
[image]

Incase nothing i suspet to be wrong is the issue
This is a github repo with my code. Thank you

I tried making changes to the slice, the fetchPosts function and the PostsList component but still no outcome.

Comment: Why are you doing this `state.posts = state.posts.concat(loadedPosts)`?

Comment: @ksav you mean why directly mutating? if it's that then it's because the tutorial i was using said you are allowed to directly mutate state when you are inside a createSlice, because of emmer js

Comment: Yes i understand that RTK uses Immer. But why are you concatenating in the first place?

Comment: In general that's the code from the tutorial, i actually just followed the instructions, but the fact that it isnt working makes me feel i made a mistake somewhere. I've spent over a day trying to find my error and can't so that's why i'm asking.

Comment: 1) The tutorial author may not be using React 18. 2) This Issue won't present itself in production.

Comment: That said, there's probably no need to concatenate unless there's some kind of infinite pagination happening.

Comment: yeah i got rid of concatenation and just assigned the posts state to the loadedPost. Thank you, your comment was instrumental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [useEffect will be called twice on mount since React 18 when you are in development under Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72238236/5385381).

In `PostsList`, this means that you may not realise that you are dispatching `fetchPosts` twice. e.g.
`dispatch(fetchPosts())`

We can see this happening in the Redux devtools.

[image]

Then in `PostSlice` you are concatenating the results of the second `fetchPosts` thunk to the end of the results of the first `fetchPost` thunk. e.g.

`state.posts = state.posts.concat(loadedPosts)`

Instead, change this line to:
`state.posts = loadedPosts;`

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it would be something related to useEffect acting different due to version changes. This worked thank you very much.