# Laravel + InertiaJS + ReactJS Components Renders Twice

Tags: reactjs, inertiajs

So I am currently developing a web application and noticed that some of my components renders twice and I am not really sure why and also that console.log appears twice in the console. I am sure that I am only calling the console.log once and the toast once.

[image]

[image]

I have read about the strict mode in reactjs but I am unsure if it is enabled or not since I can't find it in my source code.

Here's my app.jsx

```
import '../css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../css/bootstrap-icons-1.10.3/bootstrap-icons.css'
import '../css/dhca-base.sass'

import React from 'react';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,

    resolve: name => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx', { eager: true })
        return pages[`./Pages/${name}.jsx`]
    },
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        createRoot(el).render(<App {...props} />)
    },
})
```

I also have the reactjs development extensions in my browser and it shows me a warning sign near the Inertia title.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Comment: How would I be able to turn the strict mode off?

Comment: By removing the `StrictMode` tag that wraps `App` inside `index.js`, but I don't recommend it. Go through the answer to the above post; you would find more information.

Comment: the thing is, I don't have a StrictMode tag around my App

Comment: Look for `StrictMode` in your editor search input. Aren't you using React version 18?

Comment: I am using ReactJS along side with InertiaJS, if that helps, not entirely sure about what version I am using exactly

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file? If so, look inside for the version.

Comment: ah yes, and upon looking into it, I am using version 18

Comment: thank you very much for the help @yousoumar I have finally figured it out thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything is set up correctly and I was just not using the useEffect hook correctly.