# NextJS useEffects Fired twice

Tags: react-hooks, next.js

I'm having problem with useEffect it fired twice when the page rendered my code below

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!jwt) {
      console.log('you are not login');
    } else {
      console.log(cookie.GREEN_COOKIE);
    }

    fetchEvents();
  }, []);
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Something is causing your component to re-render.

Without seeing any other code or props of the component it's difficult to say what.

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/35822