# React- useEffect triggering multiple times with empty array dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener

I am new to React and I am trying to understand how this piece of code works. I was following a tutorial and the author's code can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/judygab/web-dev-projects/blob/main/personal-portfolio/src/components/NavBar.js

I don't understand how this hook `useEffect` can continuously run even though it has an empty dependency array?

To my understanding, when you put an empty array as the second parameter, **it will only fire off once**, when the component is rendered to the DOM.

What exactly is happening so that it fires every time you scroll upon and down the page. I suspect that the definition I have is either not fully complete or the `window.addEventListener` is continuously adding/removing from the DOM.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 50) {
        setScrolled(true);
        
      } else {
        setScrolled(false);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    }
  }, [])
```

I have tried logging messages to the console at different points in the code but I am not sure why they would be firing continuously. Any explanation of what's going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try with useLayoutEffect.

Comment: it means your component is being unmounted and mounted again

Comment: It will fire twice if you have react 18: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react

Comment: Is the effect actually being fired multiple times, or is it just the `onScroll` function you've added added to the scroll event? (The effect should run once, applying the event listener, but the event listener will repeatedly call `onScroll` when a scroll event occurs)

Comment: @DBS Reading your comment, I think I now understand. It's not that the `useEffect` is firing multiple times, it's that it creates a function `onScroll` and then sends that function to the window, which fires multiple times. That makes sense! 
Thank you all for the quick responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not true ,`useEffect` runs the code within it only once when you pass an empty deps array. You might have confused with `onScroll` handler that fires for every scroll point you on the UI.

Comment: I was confused. That makes more sense. Thank you!