# Returns the same element 2 times

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to do a Netflix clone app and i have an issue. Im watching a video while doing it and im doing what i see in the video.

I have added a banner image with this code.

Code :

```js
function Banner() {
  return ( 
    <header 
      className="banner" 
      style={{
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundImage: 'url("https://thelesfilms.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/netflix-banner.jpg?w=640")',
        backgroundPosition: "center center",
      }}>
    </header>
  );
}
```

CSS :

```css
.banner {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

When the guy in the video writes the same code, it works correctly and one image appears as expected. When i do the same thing, there are double image and i dont understand why. (I didnt return Banner function 2 times in HomeScreen.js.)

Comment: Can you share the parent component as well ?

Comment: I am sorry but there is nothing to share in parent component. I am just returning Banner.js on HomeScreen with doing <Banner />

Comment: Are they both your banner?

Comment: maybe try to set the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat?retiredLocale=de I know you have set it to cover, but nothing else to make from what I see.

Comment: I can only assume that you are trying to write the clone in react, right? Try to remove the <ReactStrictMode> Compontent from your App Component. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react

Comment: This is not pure javascript. Please insure to include tags or info regarding what framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `?w=640` from the image URL,

```js
function Banner() {
  return ( 
    <header 
      className="banner" 
      style={{
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundImage: `url("https://thelesfilms.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/netflix-banner.jpg")`,
        backgroundPosition: "center center",
      }}>
    </header>
  );
}
```

```css
.banner {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```