# Re-rendering with <React.Strict Mode> and fabric's canvas instantiation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs, react-strictmode

I am creating a fabric canvas and buttons that instantiate shapes that should be selectable. I don't understand why my component is being re-rendered twice in the following scenario. Because of this my fabric shapes are not selectable. However when I remove `<React.StrictMode>` from my index.tsx file, rendering occurs once and my shapes are selectable. I could remove `<React.StrictMode>` but I don't believe that is the best solution. Demo below:

```js
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useEffect, useRef } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const styles = {};

const CanvasComponent = ({ id }) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('init canvas'); // displayed twice with <React.StrictMode>
        canvasRef.current = initCanvas();
    }, []);

    const initCanvas = () => (
        canvasRef.current = new fabric.Canvas(`canvas-${id}`, {
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
        })
    );

    const addShape = (shapeType: string) => {
        let shape: fabric.Object;
        switch (shapeType) {
            case 'circle':
                shape = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 100 });
                break;
            case 'rectangle':
                shape = new fabric.Rect({ width: 60, height: 70, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100 });
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        canvasRef.current.add(shape);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => addShape('circle')}>Add Circle</button>
            <button onClick={() => addShape('rectangle')}>Add Rectangle</button>
            <div className={styles.canvasContainer}>
                <canvas id={`canvas-${id}`}></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function StrictModeEnabled() {
    return <StrictMode><h1>Strict Mode Enabled</h1><CanvasComponent id={1} /></StrictMode>;
}

function StrictModeDisabled() {
    return <Fragment><h1>Strict Mode Disabled</h1><CanvasComponent id={2} /></Fragment>;
}

const strictModeEnabledRoot = createRoot(document.getElementById("strict-mode-enabled"));
strictModeEnabledRoot.render(<StrictModeEnabled />);

const strictModeDisabledRoot = createRoot(document.getElementById("strict-mode-disabled"));
strictModeDisabledRoot.render(<StrictModeDisabled />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://www.unpkg.com/fabric@5.3.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="strict-mode-enabled"></div>
<div id="strict-mode-disabled"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

[Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react) has great answers describing why this is happening and a generalised solution.

## Solution

In your case, you need to clean up the instantiated canvas. I'm not familiar with Fabric, however from reading the documentation the [`dispose` method](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#dispose) seems suitable:

> ##### `dispose() → {fabric.Canvas}`
>
> Clears a canvas element and removes all event listeners

You'll need to return a function from the `useEffect` that calls the above method. It is good practice to return a function that does cleanup from `useEffect`s, as elaborated in the linked question. A working demo is also below:

```js
const { Fragment, StrictMode, useEffect, useRef } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const styles = {};

const CanvasComponent = ({ id }) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('init canvas'); // displayed twice with <React.StrictMode>
        canvasRef.current = initCanvas();
        
         return () => canvasRef.current.dispose();
    }, []);

    const initCanvas = () => (
        canvasRef.current = new fabric.Canvas(`canvas-${id}`, {
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
        })
    );

    const addShape = (shapeType: string) => {
        let shape: fabric.Object;
        switch (shapeType) {
            case 'circle':
                shape = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 100 });
                break;
            case 'rectangle':
                shape = new fabric.Rect({ width: 60, height: 70, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100 });
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        canvasRef.current.add(shape);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => addShape('circle')}>Add Circle</button>
            <button onClick={() => addShape('rectangle')}>Add Rectangle</button>
            <div className={styles.canvasContainer}>
                <canvas id={`canvas-${id}`}></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function StrictModeEnabled() {
    return <StrictMode><h1>Strict Mode Enabled</h1><CanvasComponent id={1} /></StrictMode>;
}

const strictModeEnabledRoot = createRoot(document.getElementById("strict-mode-enabled"));
strictModeEnabledRoot.render(<StrictModeEnabled />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://www.unpkg.com/fabric@5.3.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="strict-mode-enabled"></div>
```