# Fabric.js and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, redux, fabricjs

I'm in the process of building an online editing app using fabric.js and React. I initialize the canvas and store its reference in Redux. With this reference, I'm able to add text or shapes to the canvas. However, I'm currently facing an issue: once I add text to the canvas, it's visible but unresponsive to user interactions. To simplify the replication of the problem, I've used a ref instead of Redux and provided a CodeSandbox link where you can see the issue in action for a better understanding.

https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-paper-m7ckv8

Please make sure your solution uses functional components of React.

I've been working on this problem for the past two days, but I haven't made any significant progress. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-rendering with <React.Strict Mode> and fabric's canvas instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885346/re-rendering-with-react-strict-mode-and-fabrics-canvas-instantiation)

Comment: @Wing thanks for your link, but it didn't help me. My question is a bit different. If I add an object while initialising canvas, the object is selectable but if I add it afterwards it does not get selected.

Comment: I tested the solution in the linked Q&A and it resolves your issue.

Comment: @Wing can you please share your code here, I did the same but it didn't work for me. Maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: In the `useEffect` in `FabricCanvas` you just need to return a function to dispose the canvas (`return () => canvasRef.current.dispose();`). See this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-snyder-5jrjck?file=/src/FabricCanvas.jsx:737-782) of your sandbox.