# Nextjs Client Component with Suspense fallback not wokring

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13, react-suspense

I am loading a client component inside a server component but trying to show a fallback loader until the data is fetched inside the client competent via API.

**I have the following server component which contains a client component**

```
import { LoggedInUserModel } from "@/models/common/logged-in-user-model";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import ProfileLoading from "./loading22";
const UserProfile = dynamic(() => import("./components/userProfile"), {
  ssr: false,
});

const MyProfile = async () => {
 const user: LoggedInUserModel = await userService.getUser();
  return (
    <>
      <div className="row mt-3 justify-content-md-center">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-8">
          <nav
            aria-label="breadcrumb"
            className="p-3 bg-white rounded-3 shadow-sm mb-4"
          >
            <ol className="breadcrumb mb-0">
              <li className="breadcrumb-item">
                <a className="text-decoration-none">
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-user"></i> My Profile
                </a>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <UserProfile user={user} />

      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyProfile;
```

**And my Client Component UserProfile is**

```
"use client";
import { UserProfileModel } from "./../../../../models/User/user-profile-model";
import { Suspense, lazy, use, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import fetchClientData from "@/lib/fetchClientData";
import { LoggedInUserModel } from "@/models/common/logged-in-user-model";
import ProfileLoading from "../loading22";
import React from "react";
const AbcProfile = lazy(() => import("./abcprofile"));

type UserProfileProps = {
  user: LoggedInUserModel;
};
const UserProfile = ({ user }: UserProfileProps) => {
 

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<h2>Data loading...........</h2>}>
      <AbcProfile />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default UserProfile;
```

**AbcProfile Component:**

```
import { use, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const AbcProfile = () => {
  use(
    fetch(`/api/user/profile/6490986e0d0ce1756d2b491b`).then((res) =>
      res.json()
    )
  );

  return <h2>Data loaded</h2>;
};

export default AbcProfile;
```

> **When I run the code it does show the fallback loader but the API is called 4 times to get the data from the server. Why? How to properly
> use suspense in the client component with nextjs?**

Comment: Maybe it's a [strict mode thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react). Also, I'm not sure if this `use` function is in the stable version of React.

Comment: this is happening to me did you figure out why?