# useEffect with no deps trigger browser router twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component called categories.js which will be called in App.js, there is a useEffect in categories.js as the following

```
useEffect(() => {

    const fetchCategories = async () => {
        console.log('fetchCategories');
        try {
            const response = await apiClient.get('/category/group');
            console.log(response.data.data);
            setCategories(response.data.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    fetchCategories();

    console.log('use effect 123');

},  []);
```

in the return section, i have a browser router like this

```
    return (

            <div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/posts/:postId/page/:page" element={<OpenPostsOverlayByRoute />} />
                </Routes>
                {Object.keys(categories).map((group) => (
....
```

here is a OpenPostsOverlayByRoute element also in categories.js

```
const OpenPostsOverlayByRoute = () => {

    const { postId, page } = useParams();
    console.log('OpenPostsOverlayByRoute: ' + postId);
    /*useEffect(() => {
        // Update the state using the provided setter
        setRoutePostId(postId);
        console.log('OpenPostsOverlayByRoute: ' + postId);
    }, [postId);*/


}
```

when i access the page https://localhost:3000/posts/235/page/2, it will print OpenPostsOverlayByRoute 235 twice, do anyone know how to handle this situation?

------------------temp solution---------------
in return section:

```
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/posts/:postId/page/:page" element={<OpenPostsOverlayByRoute setIsRoute={setIsRoute} />} />
        </Routes>
```

in use effect:

```
    setIsRoute(2);
```

in OpenPostsOverlayByRoute

```
if (isRoute == 1) {

}
```

Comment: Possible cause: [Strict Mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode)

Comment: @Yousaf strictmode already removed

Comment: Check the component hierarchy and make sure none of its parent/ancestor components are re-rendered twice.

Comment: Can you fix your code for extra clarity - you have commented out the effect which you say is being run twice.

Comment: i added a temp solution....... it works but it makes the code getting more mess.......

Comment: What *exactly* is being "triggered twice" and how exactly are you determining this? Please [edit] to add specific details about the issue and what you have done to debug it. I suspect your console logs as ***unintentional side-effects*** is misleading you. I suspect also your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72238175/8690857.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the first time component will render, so it will give console, and then again, you're calling an API in useEffect and changing the parent state, so child component will get re-rendered, that's why console is output twice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: useEffect() has an empty array as its set of dependencies, so it will only be run once after initial rendering. (I learned this today actually. The difference between empty array `[]` and not passing anything as a dependency. So actually this code would only run once, regardless of re-rendering.

Comment: Hi @TjadClark, Yes, you're right in regards of working of useEffect, but I am trying to say actually will work like:
At the first render, `useEffect` will not run and the component will get mounted on to DOM and the console will be printed.
Then, after the mount, `useEffect` will run and will change the `categories` state which will cause the whole component to re-render. Now, `OpenPostsOverlayByRoute` this component, as a child component, will also re-render. Hence, the console will be printed again.

Hope, it's clear.

Comment: One thing I noticed with my comment, is that the OP is talking about there nested component (which does have a dependency), though I don't think this dependency results in double rendering due to the `postId` changing as it is only set once

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior in development mode

https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-twice-when-the-component-mounts

The reason for this is to help with debugging.

> To help you find bugs, in development React runs setup and cleanup one extra time before the setup. This is a stress-test that verifies your Effect’s logic is implemented correctly. If this causes visible issues, your cleanup function is missing some logic. The cleanup function should stop or undo whatever the setup function was doing. The rule of thumb is that the user shouldn’t be able to distinguish between the setup being called once (as in production) and a setup → cleanup → setup sequence (as in development). See common solutions.