# Rendering Twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, peerjs

I tried to build a video chat application using React and peerjs. and below is pieces of code that handles it.

```
const randomPeerId = uuidv4();
const peer = new Peer(randomPeerId);

export function VideoCall() {
  const [peerId, setPeerId] = useState("");

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!peer) console.log(`No peer detected`);
    console.log('peer exist: ', peer.id);

    peer.on('connection',(conn)=>{
      console.log(`got a connection`);
    })
  },[])


  const connect = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const connection = peer.connect(peerId);
    connection.send('Hi')
  };

  return (
    <div id="video">
      {randomPeerId}
      <h1>Video Call</h1>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={connect}>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="recepientId"
            placeholder="Enter Peer ID to connect"
            onChange={(e) => setPeerId(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button>Connect</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here even though I click connect once. we can see that on the other side its console.log() twice. the same happened when I created the Peer objected inside the function. so, because its getting created twice I have to keep creating of peer object outside the function. (iam an aboslute beginner in react)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's because during development with `StrictMode` React mounts, and immediately unmounts and then mount your component to help catch bugs (among others).

In your case, for example, you should clean up the connection, like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(!peer) console.log(`No peer detected`);
  console.log('peer exist: ', peer.id);

  peer.on('connection',(conn)=>{
    console.log(`got a connection`);
  })
  // This function will get called when the component gets unmounted:
  return () => {
     peer.destroy()
  }
},[])
```

To know more about this behaviour, checkout this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react).

Answer (score -1):

You can disable react strict mode,  in your app file you should find a tag ReactSrict mode just remove it, but this only happens in dev