# React rerendering causing countdown timer to skip a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I built a countdown timer in React using useEffect and setTimeout from the following code below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./App.css";

// Countdown Timer
export default function App() {

  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => { setTime((a) => a - 1); 
    }, 1000);
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <div className="container">

      <h1>Countdown</h1>
      { time <= 0 ? <p>Time's Up!</p> : <p>{time}</p> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

It works fine except for the beginning, where it goes from 10 to 8..7..6..5..etc, skipping nine. I'm not sure what I should modify to get nine back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the way `setTimeout` works in your code. When you use `setTimeout` inside the `useEffect` with a dependency on the `time` state, the timer is set to decrease the time by 1 second after each render. This means that when the component initially renders, the time state is 10, but the timer immediately starts and reduces it to 9 seconds.

To be more specific, `useEffect` will run regardless of whether the dependencies have changed or not on the *first render*. After the initial run, the `useEffect` will continue to run each time `time` changes because you've specified `[time]` in the dependency array. So, after the initial run, changes to `time` will trigger the `useEffect` to execute.

You can modify your code this way to fix the problem:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (time > 0) {
      setTime((prevTime) => prevTime - 1);
    }
  }, 1000);

  // Clear the timer when the component unmounts or when time reaches 0
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [time]);
```

Answer (score 1):

React in development mode re-mounts your component twice to catch bugs in things like `useEffect` that aren't expecting to be mounted multiple times.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72238236/135978) for more details on *why* that's the case.

In this case, it caught a bug.  The issue is that you don't tell React how to *cancel* an effect if the tree hasn't been mounted but it needs to be unmounted.

Add a cancellation callback that calls `clearTimeout` and your issue will be resolved:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => setTime((a) => a - 1), 1000);
    // The new bit ⬇︎
    return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
  }, [time]);
```