# How to run mutation on page load in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, trpc

My goal is to run a mutation as soon page loads and update the page when the mutation is complete, i.e. This is what I am trying at the moment:

```
useEffect(() => {
  void trpc.generateArticle.useMutation();
}, []);
```

The problem is that `useEffect()` runs twice when in development mode.

I understand why – it is covered in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react).

However, I don't understand what is the proper way to implement this pattern (starting mutation as soon as page loads) if I am not supposed to use `useEffect` here.

How to run mutation on page load in Next.js and run it only once?