# Why useEffect hook with empty dependency is triggered twice in Expo Router file layout?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

Howdy fellow programmators!

**Let me first state the issue.**

In my React Native app, I use the Expo Router package for the app layout. Once a user signs in, the main page view renders and triggers useEffect with an empty dependency array **TWICE** and fires 2 HTTP requests towards the server.

**App Layout**

```
app
- _layout.tsx
  (auth)
  - _layout.tsx
  - index.tsx
  - login.tsx
  ...
  (tabs)
  - _layout.tsx
  - index.tsx
    chats
    - _layout.tsx
    - index.tsx
    - [chat].tsx
    profile
    - _layout.tsx
    - index.tsx
    ...  
  (setup)
  - wizard.tsx
```

As stated above, once a user signs in and gets redirected from `(auth)/login.tsx` to `(tabs)/index.tsx`, the `index.tsx` file fires twice the useEffect hook with empty dependency array.

Any ideas what's the reason ?

Thanks!

Comment: I do recall react 18 causing effects to run twice, and the behavior being labeled as expected rather than a bug

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react