# toggle doesn't work when you click on react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have code that toggles the value on click from an object in an array. But the console log always shows 1 0 (doubles the values)....

[image]

Can please tell what the issue could be?

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [Btns, setBtns] = useState([
    { componentId: 0 },
    { componentId: 0 }
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(event) => {
          setBtns((oldArr) => {
            let newArr = [...oldArr];
            newArr[0].componentId = newArr[0].componentId === 0 ? 1 : 0;
            console.log(newArr[0].componentId);
            return newArr;
          });
        }}
      >
        Button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: @mandy8055, same issue :(

Comment: Okay... is there some way to replicate this issue on maybe [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or similar? because by looking at the code it's difficult to just guess the issue

Comment: @mandy8055, Not yet, but I need time to do it in the sandbox.

Comment: ok just a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would do

Comment: @mandy8055, I added it, but the code doesn't play. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @mandy8055, same - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quizzical-wiles-6rvntg

Comment: Instead of comparing with 1 and 0 try working with actual true or false. There seems some issue with Proxy objects when comparing to 0 as false.

Comment: During a local dev session, state gets updated twice.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu, I tried it but the problem is the same, I added the sandbox link (above)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, why is this happening? It's weird.

Comment: I updated your script at the bottom. All I did was run it through Prettier and click the checkbox next to Babel. The snippet does not show this behavior.

Comment: Do you have `<StrictMode>` wrapped around your `<App>` component in your `index.jsx`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, yes

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, React does additional checks on the component state when in dev mode with strictmode wrapped around the app. The useEffect function is invoked twice. It's intentional. It's a way to identify bugs where a child component (or other components) update the parent's local state on render. Angular does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most-likely because you have your `<App>` component wrapped in `<StrictMode>` in your sandbox.

File: `index.js`

```js
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Try removing the `<StrictMode>` tags and try to see if that helps.

**Note:** Your sandbox uses strict mode, but your provided snippet does not.

---

To understand how strict mode differs from non-strict mode, see:

> [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

### Use immutable state changes

When updating state in React, it is best to not mutate the previous state. State should be treated as immutable. If you need to change a nested property, you should clone i.e. `structuredClone` the current state, before modification.

```js
const { StrictMode, useCallback, useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    { componentId: 0 },
    { componentId: 0 }
  ]);
  
  const onClick = useCallback((event) => {
    setButtons((oldArr) => {
      // Copy
      const newArr = structuredClone(oldArr);
      // Flip bit
      newArr[0].componentId = 1 - newArr[0].componentId;
      // Print
      console.log(newArr[0].componentId); // Will log twice (this is ok)
      // Return new state
      return newArr;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick} >
        Button
      </button>
      <hr />
      <div>
        {buttons.map(({ componentId }, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            Component ID: {componentId}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <StrictMode>
      <App />
    </StrictMode>
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 6rem !important; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I updated the response to include an alternative approach. This allows you to continue using strict mode. I also updated the snippet to work with React 18. The render at the very end is the only thing that needs to be changed when migrating from 17 to 18.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to React's behavior in Strict mode.

The way you are updating the state inside the setState is called an **updater function.**

In React's Strict mode, React tends to run the updated functions twice to help detect any hidden bugs.

This is mentioned on React's official Documentation.

**You can Check it [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#my-initializer-or-updater-function-runs-twice).**

However, I think the code used to update the state is somehow faulty.

You should not mutate the state directly by calling newArr[0].componentId

Instead, you can do this:

```
let newArr = [...oldArr];
    newArr[0] = { ...newArr[0], componentId: newArr[0].componentId === 0 ? 1 : 0 };
    return newArr;
```

Check my [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reverent-jackson-tdmpp3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A17%2C1)