Hook doesn't update data immediatly since React 18
We have a strange behaviour since we updated from React 16 to React 18.
We have data that we determine through a hook.
This worked with React 16, now with React 18 it seems so that the component is still rendered with the old data value first, only then is data updated. Unfortunately I only have pseudo code, but maybe someone can help.
import * as _ from "lodash";
import * as React from "react";

const useData = (id: string): string[] => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(DataManager.selectCurrentDataById(id));

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleDataChange = () => {
            const newData = DataManager.selectCurrentDataById(id);

            if (_.isEqual(newData, data)) return;
            console.log("set new data ", newData);
            setData(newData);
        };

        handleDataChange();
        return DataManager.subscribe(handleDataChange);
    }, [data, planId]);

    console.log("return data ", data);
    return data;
};

const MatcherComponent = ({
    id,
}: { id: string }): React.ReactElement<{ id: string }> => {
    const data = useData(id);
    console.log("data ", data);
    
    return (
        <TestType type={data[0]} />
    )
}

const TestType = ({
    type,
}: { type: string }): React.ReactElement<{ type: string }> => {
    console.log("type ", type);

    return (
        <div>{type}</div>
    )
}

And the logs, if data changed:
// the data was `["type1"]`
// in React 18 it is called twice
set new data "type2"
set new data "type2"

// but then first the child component is re-rendered with the old data and this didn't
// happen in React 16
type "type1"

// then the hook seem to return the new value
return data "type2"
data "type2"

// now the value for the child component is correct
type "type2"


It's rather unclear what you are doing in the code, and all the console logs in the component body are unintentional side-effects, but does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/8690857 Or maybe this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72238175/8690857

@DrewReese Thanks. I will have a look. The strangest thing is, why this happens only in React 18 not in React 16 or 17. I would like to understand what changed, but find nothing about that.

Lots of stuff changed in React 18, and specifically with the StrictMode component it now also double-mounts the component to ensure proper effect cleanup and re-usable state. (https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development)

@DrewReese Thank you! But it fails also without strict mode and on production since React 18. Seems to be something with setState and useEffect. Can't fix it right now.

It works with flushSync
I know this is not a good way and I want to understand what has changed in React 18. Because useState has always been asynchronous. But it worked for 5 years before our update :D
import * as _ from "lodash";
import * as React from "react";
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";

const useData = (id: string): string[] => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(DataManager.selectCurrentDataById(id));

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleDataChange = () => {
            const newData = DataManager.selectCurrentDataById(id);

            if (_.isEqual(newData, data)) return;
            console.log("set new data ", newData);

            flushSync(() => {
                setData(newData);
            });
        };

        handleDataChange();
        return DataManager.subscribe(handleDataChange);
    }, [data, planId]);

    console.log("return data ", data);
    return data;
};

